# IBM DOORS - Update requirements based on attribute

Tags: ibm-doors

Hi have a module in DOORS for the customer requirements, but now I received a new PDF file which contains updated/new requirements. I am able to convert the PDF file to ReqIf and create a new module using an internal tool of the company.

How can I then with two modules, merge into one based on a specified attribute which contains unique IDs on both modules.

Module A:

- Global ID 1
- Global ID 2

Module B:

- Global ID 2 - new info in another attribute
- Global ID 4

Module C (A+B):

- Global ID 1
- Global ID 2 - new info in another attribute
- Global ID 4

Answer (score 0):

I assume that except new info in another attribute, rest all are same between two modules.
Following script updates the current module with new module new information

```
Module m = current

Object ob, ob1

ModName_ mod = module "full path of new module here"

Module m1 = read(fullName(mod), false)

for ob in m do
{
int objID = intOf(ob."Absolute Number""")

ob1 = object(objID, m1)

if(ob."Attribute Name" != ob1."Attribute Name") //If new info in another attribute
{
ob."Attribute Name" = ob1."Attribute Name"
}
}
```

Comment: The new info is on the object text and/or heading.

Answer (score 0):

I modified script according to your comment

```
Module m = current

Object ob, ob1

ModName_ mod = module "full path of new module here"

Module m1 = read(fullName(mod), false)

for ob in m do
{
int objID = intOf(ob."Absolute Number""")

ob1 = object(objID, m1)

if((ob."Object Heading" != ob1."Object Heading") || (ob."Object Text" != ob1."Object Text"))
{
ob."Object Heading" = ob1."Object Heading"
ob."Object Text" = ob1."Object Text"
}
}
```